# strcmp() returning -1 for different strings

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.casa.gov.au/rpa-operator-certificate-holders");
$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
if(!empty($html)){ 

    $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); 
    $pokemon_xpath  = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);
    $pokemon_row    = $pokemon_xpath->query('//tr');

    if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
        $s4 = "4 ONE 4 REAL ESTATE PTY LTD ";
        $s5 = ($pokemon_row[2]->firstChild->nodeValue);
        echo strcmp($s4,$s5); 
    }

}
?>
```

From the above code I am  trying to compare string from the table of this site("https://www.casa.gov.au/rpa-operator-certificate-holders") but I didn't get output as 0 when I am using strcmp(), instead I am getting output as -1

Comment: did you checked value of `$s5` by doing `var_dump($s5);`. check and let us know what it outputs?seems like extra spaces are there

Comment: when i used var_dump($s5); i am getting string(19) " " ... i thing it is a space instead of NULL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the extra whitespace around the strings you are comparing.  If you add

```
echo ">".$s4."<>".$s5."<";
```

you get

```
>4 ONE 4 REAL ESTATE PTY LTD <>
            4 ONE 4 REAL ESTATE PTY LTD          <
```

You could easily change the compare to...

```
echo strcmp(trim($s4),trim($s5));
```

Comment: I have tried with... echo ">".$s4."<>".$s5."<";
        echo "<br>";
        echo strcmp(trim($s4),trim($s5)); ---> Yet it is returning me 27 only now.

Comment: I may have confused things by using `<>`, try `echo "#".$s4."#".$s5."#";` to see the strings.

Comment: if I am using echo "#".$s4."#".$s5."#"; means I am getting. the output as follows ……….. #4 ONE 4 REAL ESTATE PTY LTD# #

Comment: That looks as though it's not finding the value in the HTML.  Try displaying your HTML page (or saving it to a file) and check the contents.